# Comparing user input data to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database

so i've recently got a job at a market, and they got a lot of PLU's that i need to know. So for helping me, i'm trying to do something to help me.

I've created a database with some of the items that look like this:

```
id art img plu_code
```

and in my index.php, after connecting to database and selecting a random id to show

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM produto ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $imagem_produto = $row["imagem"];
        $nome_produto = $row["artigo"];
        $plu_produto = $row["plu"];

        echo '<center><tr>
                  <td><img height="150" width="150" src="'.$imagem_produto.'"></td><br> 
                  <td>'.$nome_produto.'</td><br>
                  <td>'.$plu_produto.'</td>  
              </tr></center>';
    }
    $result->free();

    if ($plu_produto === $_GET['U']) {
        echo "Correct. Please wait!";
        header("Refresh:3");
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong.';
    }
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="U"/>
<input type="submit" />
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

How do i compare the user input to the db and then show if it's correct or wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Use a `SELECT` query, with a `WHERE` condition that tests whether the entered code exists.

Comment: Hello, i've updated the code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** like comparing the user input to the db.

Your code

```
if ($_POST['U'] === $plu_produto) {
```

compares with the last row read by the while loop which is not as expected.

After connecting to the database, have code to show all data which will show up in the first run. And after the user input you should select the relevant rows from the database itself which matches with **"U"** where there should not be any while loop but the sql select itself should return only one row.

Comment: Tried this? Give feedback for further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You should just query for the specific PLU, not the entire table.

You also need to use `$_POST`, not `$_GET`, since the form has `method="POST"`.

```
if (isset($_POST['U'])) {
    $plu_produto = $_POST['U'];
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM produto WHERE plu = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $plu_produto);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Correct. Please wait!";
        header("Refresh:3");
    }else{
        echo 'Wrong.';
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for this! What do you recommend me to read to get more knowledge about php?

Comment: There are many textbooks and tutorial web sites, I'm sorry I don't have any specific recommendations. How did you get the job to do this without any experience?

Comment: Hello, the job has nothing to do about programing, this is for personal use only. I've got a job at a retail market, and i have 150 codes that i need to know. So instead of reading them with paper, i now have some "game" that will help me :p

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought this was a task that was assigned to you.